# Flask web page routing forward slash at end or not?

Tags: html, flask

When specifying routing routes for pages in a main.py file in Flask eg:

```
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

I get an error when I browse to localhost:nnnn/about as the browser automatically appends a trailing forward slash to the page (ie localhost:nnnn/about/).

Is there a way to handle this issue as a 'once only' configuration or do I need to have two app route tags above every function? ie:

```
@app.route('/home')
@app.route('/home/')
def ....
```

Comment: i think the good practice use '/' in all places like the convention, it helps avoids mistakes with redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flask doc has mentioned this: [Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/quickstart/#variable-rules).

In short:

- route has a '/': with or without '/' is ok, without a trailing slash will be redirected to the canonical URL with the trailing slash.
- route doesn't have a '/': only URL without trailing slash can access to it. With a trailing slash will cause the 404 error.

Comment: For those users with a similar issue, delete the browsers cache so it doesn't force append a forward slash.